# Regex for the number that should not start with some specific two digit numbers

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regex for following rules

1. No characters – only numbers are allowed to enter
2. Numbers must contain not less than 8 digits
3. Numbers and combinations, starting as follows should not be allowed:

   - [3.1]  - Any number starting with 0 (zero) and with 1 (one);
   - [3.2] - Numbers starting with 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, and 27.

I am able to achieve regex for points `1`, `2` and `3.1` like this

```
^[2-9]{1}[0-9]{7,}$
```

But I am not able to find solution for point `3.2`

This is one of the options I started with, this regex matches the string that must start with 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, or 27.

```
^([2][0-7])[2-9]{1}[0-9]{7,}$
```

I just have to find the negation of this first condition.

Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than trying to negate the `20-27` condition, just match numbers that start with `28` or `29` instead:

```
^(?:2[89]|[3-9]\d)\d{6,}$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ei1mQ1/1)